# Unable to read Project file “project.vcxproj” in Visual Studio Community 2019. unexpected token 's' was found?

Tags: c++

I have just started to learn c++ and when I wanted to put it in practice through visual studio community 2019, I wanted to create a project it showing this error

[image]

what shall I do?

Answer (score 2):

The apostrophe in the path `E:\Software\Other programs\Coding\IDE's\` is clashing with the way how a condition is specified in an internal `.props`-file. Try installing Visual Studio into some other path, without apostrophes.

Comment: Good eye! Microsoft giving users freedom to use special characters in directory names is apparently biting themselves in the butt xD

Comment: `IDE's` is a [grocers apostrophe](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/greengrocer%27s_apostrophe) anyway and is grammatically incorrect